# Publish-AzureWebsiteProject Failing in Release Mode

Tags: c#, azure, teamcity, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to deploy an Azure Web Service (a Web API project) through TeamCity via a Powershell script that uses the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject command and supplies the "Configuration" parameter as "Release".

There is a separate TC build configuration for the same project in Debug mode that succeeds, however, the new version I made to deploy in Release mode fails. A previous step which builds the project (using the TC built-in "Visual Studio Solution" command) succeeds, but by the time it gets to the publish step, it fails, claiming that there is a build error.

The log reports this as the error:

```
File.cs(12,7): error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'static' is a keyword
File.cs(12,14): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

The line it is complaining about looks like:

```
using static MyPackage.Extensions.ExtensionClass;
```

However, I can deploy this project in Debug mode through TeamCity, I can build it locally in both Debug and Release mode, and I can successfully do a local file publish in Release mode.

Does anybody have any ideas? My first thought was it was using a different compile tools version than I was using locally, but it doesn't make sense that it would differ depending on the build configuration.

Comment: remove "static" from your statement and see if it helps.

Comment: I know I can change the code to get around this, but I'd like to understand the root cause of why it can publish in Debug but not Release, especially if this error comes up again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If your package is a published zip, then you can try the Kudu Rest API way of publishing it. Even initially when i used `Publish-AzureWebsiteproject` I faced similar issues. This is the code i've used for successful deployment.

```
$creds = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $functionAppName/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow `r`n"Deploying Azure Functions..."
$apiUrl = "https://" + $functionAppName +".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot"
$filePath = ".\PublishedOutput.zip"
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Headers -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```